# Переключение между окнами в swift

Tags: ios, swift

Как с помощью кнопки перейти на другое окно(Например: из VievController в TabbleViewController), при этом необходимо, чтобы кнопка фоном совершала определенные команды(Например: присвоить текст, написанный на кнопке, лейблу в другом окне)?

Comment: что пробовали, что не получилось?

Comment: если честно, то просто не знаю, как это сделать. Знаю, что можно сделать привязку с помощью CTRL, но не знаю, как сделать побочные действия при этом.

Comment: @Goncharoff Укажите в метках вопроса о какой операционной системе идёт речь (iOS, tvOS или macOS). И зачем вы пишете о CTRL?

Comment: я имею ввиду: если зажать CTRL на кнопке и перетянуть на нужное окно, то эта кнопка будет открывать это окно.(Операционная система - iOS)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko есть какие-нибудь варианты?

Comment: создать кнопку, по нажатию совершать ваши действия, после совершения действий создать новый контроллер и попросить нав контроллер добавить новый в стек. по этому я и спрашивал что именно не получается

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko если несложно, можете написать пример кода?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте для перехода на новый контроллер

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "ваш сигвей(переход)", sender: nil)
```

Используйте для подготовки перехода

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

if segue.identifier == "ваш сигвей(переход)" {
        let nav = segue.destination as! ВашViewController
       nav.переменная(открываемого контроллера) = "Дядя Вася"


    }
}
```